# Can Never Seem To Login No Matter What

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm a complete newb at PHP and I have been banging my head over this for a week trying different tutorials all for the sake of a basic login which none of them ever work.

I stumbled across one where I was able to get my registration to work funny enough, but I have never been successful logging in when it comes to matching the parameters and what's in the database and I cannot find the reason as to why.

I have copied and pasted the code and changed a few names from the tutorial's website -> `die('We encountered some problems');`
I have re-written the code over and over -> `die('We encountered some problems');`
Checked for hours straight for any tiny errors, none and still -> `die('We encountered some problems');`

I just cannot log in.

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

  $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username = :username');
  $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $records->execute();
  $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
  die('We have a log in');
} else {
  die('We encountered some problems');
}
endif;
```

I have dropped the password column in my database and added it back in again, then put new passwords, still a no go it just goes straight to the `die('We encountered some problems');`.

Basically this is the same message I receive all the time even upon entering the right password and username over and over again.

Please help me, I'm desperate to find out the reason why everything I have tried concerning this login is just faulty full stop. But yet I am able to register and add in new information to the database... it makes no sense to me.

---UPDATE---

```
<?php
var_dump($results, $_POST);

require 'connection.php';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

  $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username = :username');
  $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $records->execute();
  $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['Password'])) {
  die('We have a log in');
} else {
  die('We encountered some problems');
}
endif;
```

Changed `$results['password']` to `$results['Password']` and also added `var_dump($results, $_POST);`, unfortunately the results remain the same output as mentioned before.

Only new output is this `NULL array(3) { ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" ["login"]=> string(5) "Login" } We encountered some problems` after adding the var_dump.

Comment: You're selecting `Password`; but checking `$results['password']` - PHP is case sensitive when it comes to array keys

Comment: You're selecting `Password` but you're using `password`. PHP array keys are case sensitive. If that doesnt help, try doing `var_dump($results, $_POST);` and comparing if the 2 passwords even look alike.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed password to Password but still receive the same error and even added the var_dump($results, $_POST); as you have mentioned and this is what I get still: NULL array(3) { ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" ["login"]=> string(5) "Login" } We encountered some problems

Comment: Where did you change it? Maybe a little too much? You should update a code in your post (e.g., UPD1: ...)

Comment: Sorry about that, I have now updated the post.

Comment: :) And why `var_dump` is flying at the top? Shouldn't it be after `records->fetch`?

Comment: Then, the issue is almost definitely in `password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['Password'])`. Check its return value.

Comment: set error reporting and come back when you have the error message.

Comment: John West - This goes to show how very newb I am at this. I moved it down and this is the result still: array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["Username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["Password"]=> string(4) "pass" } array(3) { ["username"]=> &string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(4) "pass" ["login"]=> string(5) "Login" } We encountered some problems